# GWT validation error during gwt compile - No source code available

Tags: validation, gwt, hibernate-validator

I am trying to get gwt validation working using the hibernate validator. I have followed the steps from http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation and configured my project according to the sample validation project at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/validation/

My .gwt.xml file contains:

```
<inherits name="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />
```

and my custom validation factory:

```
<replace-with class="my.package.here.client.validation.ValidatorFactory">
<when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory" />
</replace-with>
```

Validation works perfect both on client and server side in dev mode, but when trying to gwt compile I get:

```
gwtc-production:
     [java] Compiling module my.package.MyModule
     [java]    Validating newly compiled units
     [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/FutureValidatorForReadableInstant.java'
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 32: No source code is available for type org.joda.time.ReadableInstant; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/FutureValidatorForReadablePartial.java'
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 32: No source code is available for type org.joda.time.ReadablePartial; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/PastValidatorForReadableInstant.java'
     [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/SafeHtmlValidator.java'
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 22: The import org.jsoup cannot be resolved
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 23: The import org.jsoup cannot be resolved
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 35: Whitelist cannot be resolved to a type
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 40: Whitelist cannot be resolved to a type
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 40: Whitelist cannot be resolved
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 43: Whitelist cannot be resolved to a type
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 43: Whitelist cannot be resolved
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 46: Whitelist cannot be resolved to a type
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 46: Whitelist cannot be resolved
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 49: Whitelist cannot be resolved to a type
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 49: Whitelist cannot be resolved
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 52: Whitelist cannot be resolved to a type
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 52: Whitelist cannot be resolved
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 55: Whitelist cannot be resolved to a type
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 62: Jsoup cannot be resolved
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 62: Whitelist cannot be resolved to a type
     [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:gwt-user.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/super/org/hibernate/validator/engine/PathImpl.java'
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 72: The constructor NodeImpl(String) is undefined
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 84: The constructor NodeImpl(Path.Node) is undefined
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 95: The constructor NodeImpl(Path.Node) is undefined
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 202: The constructor NodeImpl(String) is undefined
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 204: The method setInIterable(boolean) is undefined for the type NodeImpl
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 209: The method setIndex(Integer) is undefined for the type NodeImpl
     [java]          [ERROR] Line 212: The method setKey(String) is undefined for the type NodeImpl
     [java]    [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

There is obviously some source jar I'm missing. I have (among others) on my classpath:

```
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar
```

I have also tried adding `joda-time-2.1.jar`, `joda-time-2.1-sources.jar`, `jsoup-1.6.3.jar` and `jsoup-1.6.3-sources.jar`.

Shouldn't inheriting the org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator take care of the super sources so I don't need to provide the sources? Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GWT is built against Hibernate Validator 4.1.0-Final and relies on some of its internals (`PathImpl`, `NodeImpl`), and apparently those have changed in Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.

Use 4.1.0-Final (or possibly 4.0.2.GA as in the sample) instead of 4.2.0.

---

Issue can be tracked in the [GWT Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7661), we should probably at least document the incompatibility explicitly.

Comment: I am using hibernate 3.6.9 actually, but switching the version of hibernate validator to 4.1.0.Final solved it. Thanks! I've created an issue for it: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7661

Comment: Thanks; edited answer to make it clear I talked about Hibernate Validator (not Hibernate ORM) and include the link to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't knew the GWT implementation of Hibernate validation. But why is GWT trying to understand code from your very Hibernate source jar? If it's GWT's own code it should come from it's gwt-user.jar or something like that.

If you agree with me, then don't include any real Hibernate jar in GWT compilation classpath. It won't need it / know it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

4.1.0 also worked for me, after some time I found out that there are a few problems with higher versions. Therefore use same versions as recommaned within the tutorial from gwt (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation.html) also I had a compile WARNING:

```
detected warnings related to 'javax.validation.constraint'. is validation- version .jar on the classpath
```

Which i fixed with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```